# Duplicate xml document in powershell variable

Tags: xml, powershell, svg

i'm struggling with duplicating an XmlDocument variable in powershell.
The script creates a new XmlDocument, adds declarations and namespaces and then generates some svg graphic nodes and saves everything as a .svg file.
So far everything works fine.

Now i want to create two slightly different .svg files (e.g. different colors) and therefore try to clone the XmlDocument variable into a new variable.

Simply assigning the variable like this:

```
[Xml]$exportSecondSVG = $exportSVG
```

will apparently just create a reference and all changes i make to the **$exportSecondSVG** document will also affect the original **$exportSVG** document.

So i tried this approach with **$exportSVG.Clone()** which also doesn't work - the **$exportSecondSVG** seems to be empty:

```
# Create new xml File with header
[xml]$exportSVG = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument

# Add xml declaration header
$decNode = $exportSVG.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0","UTF-8",$null)
$exportSVG.AppendChild($decNode) | Out-Null

# Add namespaces to svg file
$nsmgr = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($exportSVG.NameTable)
$nsmgr.AddNamespace('xlink','http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
$nsmgr.AddNamespace('rdf',"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#");
$nsmgr.AddNamespace('cc',"http://creativecommons.org/ns#");
$nsmgr.AddNamespace('dc',"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/");
$nsmgr.AddNamespace('svg',"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");

# create root svg Node
$rootSVG = $exportSVG.CreateNode("element","svg",$null)

$exportSVG.AppendChild($rootSVG) | Out-Null

# Clone original Document
[Xml]$exportSecondSVG = $exportSVG.Clone()

# DO SOME STUFF WITH $exportSVG 
# DO DIFFERENT STUFF WITH $exportSecondSVG

$exportSVG.Save("D:\File1.xml")
$exportSecondSVG.Save("D:\File2.xml") # <-- Empty File!
```

Is it possible to somehow clone / duplicate the XmlDocument variable?

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The code seems to work for me on PowerShell 5.1. You could consider using `$exportSVG.CloneNode($true)` in case there are child nodes that you are leaving out here.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Apparently there was an error in the processing part and the .Clone() did indeed work as expected.